Why does an endpoint set as .permitAll() still require authorisation?
Below you can see my SecurityFilterChain bean. I have 3 endpoints in permitAll, but /users/register still needs authorisation, while /users/register/invite/** is fine. Why is this happening?
@Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain resourceServerFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(
            auth ->
                auth.requestMatchers(
                        antMatcher("/actuator/health"),
                        antMatcher(HttpMethod.GET, "/users/register/invite/**"),
                        antMatcher(HttpMethod.POST, "/users/register"))
                    .permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(antMatcher(HttpMethod.POST, "/users/registrations/invites"))
                    .hasRole("admin")
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated())
        .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource(null)));

    http.sessionManagement(
        session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
    http.oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

    return http.build();
  }


Show us the DEBUG log. I suspect CORS.

What exactly is needing authentication even though it shouldn't? Viewing the login page? Sending the credentials? How is the request made?

You must have to disable CSRF and than this is will work

@Manuel it is csrf. It worked after .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
